# Php error Working with get varialbes

Tags: php, ajax, get

i have a php code and when i add some gets variables i get error, 500, i tested it with ajax and without ajax(directly writing the url on the adress bar)

When i go with **localhost/ajax/test.php?did=1** everything is fine but when i go with **localhost/ajax/test.php?did=1&task=1** the problem happens

*all the functions are created before on the ../php/core.php*

Here is the code

```
<?php
require '../php/core.php'; 

$did = floor($_GET['did']);

if (device_exist($did) && amlogedin() && intouch_get($uid, $did) == 2) {
    $task = floor($_GET['task']);
    $id = safestring($_GET['id']);

    switch ($task) {
        case 1:
            if (feature_removefeature($did, $fid)) {
                echo donemsg("Feature Removed");
            }
        break;
    }

    design_makefeturelist($did);
}
else {
    echo 'Sorry, some thing is wrong';
}
```

Comment: A 500 is a serious server error. The processing failed essentially when Apache received the connection and didn't get a chance to even pass it to PHP. Or maybe PHP was launched but is somehow mis-configured so Apache errored out anyways. Basically the script never even ran.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus The script was running the problem was from my code, and it is fixed now, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost sure that you've got an error in the `feature_removefeature` or `donemsg` function. Because after you set `task=1` it will enter the `case 1:` statement. You could replace the `if` with a simple `echo "lala";` to check it out.

ps. Is `$fid` already set?

Comment: You are right, i had renamed the function, that was cousing the problem, thank you